# How to write Tests on a dynamic database (inconsistent)?

Tags: database, testing, automated-tests, dynamic-data

I have a DB that has new records from different sources and may be inconsistent and this DB can be updated anytime. I'm asked to look for a strategy to test such a DB!

anyone can help me!

Comment: What do you want to test? Do you have a list of checks you want to implement on it?

Comment: I'm going to test a Microservice which implement an SAP DB .. I don't have what I'll exactly test but this is the general idea

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.